# Using IQueryable object with xUnit Theory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xunit

I have a program that runs calculations off of a SqlServer database. I want to test that those calculations are done correctly. Currently the only way I can do this is using answer ints with theory and verify that the function gives the answer int for the corresponding database row.

This is sub-optimal because I have two ints for every test, the answer and the index of the row that I want to test.

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(db.movieTable.Take(1).Select(p => p))]
public void Test1(IQueryable<movieTable> value)
{
    var result = db.movieTable.Take(1).Select(p => p).ToList().ElementAt(0).Price;
    Assert.True(value.ToList().ElementAt(0).Price == 10);
}
```

Is there a way to do this. If I run this code I get the following error: `UnitTest1.cs(19,21): error CS0182: An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type [C:\Users\co-op7\Documents\GeorgeCode\MovieSite\MovieManage.Tests\MovieManage.Tests.csproj]`

Comment: Once you call `ToList()` you don't neeed `ElementAt()`. You can use `[0]` as you would with any list

Comment: What are you trying to do? You aren't using `result` anywhere. The way you use `value` doesn't make sense either, it checks whether the *test data* has a certain price. It doesn't test your own code.

Comment: Any list or array can be converted to an `IQueryable<T>` with a call to `AsQueryable()`. If you want to test your query you can create eg an array of movies and convert it to an IQueryable with `var myArray=...;var queryable=myArray.AsQueryable()` and use it.

Comment: `Take(1).Select(p => p)` is equivalent to `Take(1)` alone. `.First()` would be better as there would be no reason to call `ToList().ElementAt(0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the point of InlineData is to use the same test logic, but isolate the differences in expected inputs and outputs.

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(1, 10.00m)]
[InlineData(2, 14.50m)]
public void Test1(int movieId, decimal expectedPrice)
{
    var result = db.movieTable.Single(p => p.Id == movieId);
    Assert.True(result.Price == expectedPrice);
}
```